# how to call functions in constructure in php

Tags: php, callback

**ENV**

PHP 5.4

HOW to call functions in constructure in php? It may looks like a variable function or *pointer function*. Code as follow get sytax error at `function $EmailAddress`. How to correct it:

```
    function __construct($username,$password,$EmailAddress,$mailserver='localhost',$servertype='imap',$port='143',$ssl = true) { 
        if($servertype=='imap') { 
            if($port=='') 
                $port='143'; 
            $strConnect='{'.$mailserver.':'.$port.'/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}'; 
        } else { 
            $strConnect='{'.$mailserver.':'.$port. '/pop3'.($ssl ? "/ssl" : "").'}INBOX'; 
        } 
        //echo $port;
        $this->server = $strConnect;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->email = $EmailAddress;
    } 
    //Connect To the Mail Box
    function $EmailAddress { 
        $this->marubox=@imap_open($this->server,$this->username,$this->password); 

        if(!$this->marubox) { 
            echo "Error: Connecting to mail server"; exit; 
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

Not works, either.

```
        $this->email = "EmailAddress";
    } 
    //Connect To the Mail Box
    function EmailAddress() { 
        $this->marubox=@imap_open($this->server,$this->username,$this->password); 

        if(!$this->marubox) { 
            echo "Error: Connecting to mail server"; exit; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is it? Your function name can not be variable whe you're declaring it in a static language construct. Use closure instead

Comment: Well how to call it in constructure.

Comment: Why use a danymic function name at all? Just make a normal function and use a function parameter for the email? Complexity is bad! Avoid it at all cost and only use it if it is worth it.

Comment: Are you trying to guess the syntax of the PHP language (instead of looking it up in the manual) or do you want to do something very specific you don't care explaining?

Comment: Apart from syntax errors (Youre second attempt does not use the new function at all) you might have a big conceptual problem here. You should rethink on what you actually want to do and how (and maybe tell us, because we dont know at all)

Comment: Yes, I was reading other people's codes. It make me confusing and I am not familiar with php syntax. Well I think that answer from Nouphal.M is closing what I think. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
function __construct($username,$password,$EmailAddress,$mailserver='localhost',$servertype='imap',$port='143',$ssl = true) { 
        if($servertype=='imap') { 
            if($port=='') 
                $port='143'; 
            $strConnect='{'.$mailserver.':'.$port.'/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}'; 
        } else { 
            $strConnect='{'.$mailserver.':'.$port. '/pop3'.($ssl ? "/ssl" : "").'}INBOX'; 
        } 
        //echo $port;
        $this->server = $strConnect;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->email = $EmailAddress;
        $this->connect_imap(); // call the connect method
    } 
    //Connect To the Mail Box
    function connect_imap() { 
        $this->marubox=@imap_open($this->server,$this->username,$this->password); 

        if(!$this->marubox) { 
            echo "Error: Connecting to mail server"; exit; 
        }
    }
```

If you want to call the function dynamically then try,

```
class test{
   private $func;
   public function __construct($functionName){
       $this->func = $functionName;
       $this->{$this->func}();      
   }

   public function my_func(){
         echo "Hello World";
   }

}

$r = new test('my_func');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have logical error in code. You must change the name of the function and call it like this.

```
function __construct($username,$password,$EmailAddress,$mailserver='localhost',$servertype='imap',$port='143',$ssl = true) { 
    if($servertype=='imap') { 
        if($port=='') 
            $port='143'; 
        $strConnect='{'.$mailserver.':'.$port.'/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}'; 
    } else { 
        $strConnect='{'.$mailserver.':'.$port. '/pop3'.($ssl ? "/ssl" : "").'}INBOX'; 
    } 
    //echo $port;
    $this->server = $strConnect;
    $this->username = $username;
    $this->password = $password;
    $this->email = $EmailAddress;

    // Call a function like this.
    $this->setupEmail();
} 
//Connect To the Mail Box
private function setupEmail() { 
    $this->marubox=@imap_open($this->server,$this->username,$this->password); 

    if(!$this->marubox) { 
        echo "Error: Connecting to mail server"; exit; 
    }
}
```